# Memory leak with a simple flatlist and a searchbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm facing this issue

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

when I'm taping a character and delete it directly inside the searchbar. I'm getting the data from a json variable so everything is on the device. I'm not making any API calls.

I'm importing the data like this `import foodData from "../config/foodData";` and it does look like this inside the foodData variable :

```
export default foodData = [
  {
    id: "10533",
    title: "Agar Agar",
    category: "Verschiedenes/Gelier- und Bindemittel",
    kcal: "160",
    protein: "2.4",
    carbohydrates: "0",
    fat: "0",
  },
  {
    id: "10536",
    title: "Agavensirup",
    synonym: "Agavendicksaft",
    category: "Süssigkeiten/Zucker und Süssstoffe",
    kcal: "295",
    protein: "0.2",
    carbohydrates: "73",
    fat: "0",
  },
  {
    id: "1478",
  ...
```

I have about 900 objects in this tab.

Finally my component with the searchbar and the flatlist looks like this :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from "react-native";
import AppText from "../components/AppText";
import CardFood from "../components/CardFood";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import foodData from "../config/foodData";
import _ from "lodash";

function AddFoodScreen(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [fulldata, setFullData] = useState([foodData]);

  const title = props.route.params.title;
  const test = foodData.map((food) => {
    return <AppText key={food.id}>{food.title}</AppText>;
  });

  const renderSeparator = () => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#3E405A",
        height: 0.4,
        width: "80%",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    />
  );

  const handleSearch = _.debounce((text) => {
    console.log(text);
    const filteredData = foodData.filter((filteredFood) => {
      if (filteredFood.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        filteredFood.synonym &&
        filteredFood.synonym.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    setData(filteredData);
  }, 500);
  return (
    <Screen>
      <View style={styles.containerSearchBar}>
        <TextInput
          clearButtonMode={"while-editing"}
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={styles.searchInput}
          placeholder="Nahrungsmittel suchen.."
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          onChangeText={(text) => handleSearch(text)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
          data={data}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
          keyExtractor={(data) => data.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <CardFood
                title={item.title}
                kcal={item.kcal}
                carbohydrates={item.carbohydrates}
                protein={item.protein}
                fat={item.fat}
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  height: 100,
                }}
                onPress={() =>
                  props.navigation.navigate("FoodDetails", {
                    ...item,
                    newTitle: title,
                  })
                }
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
```

I also used lodash in order to use a debounce in my handleSearch so that it doesnt record each and every character I tap inside de searchbar.

If somebody knows why this errror message occurs (why I have memoryleaks) would really safe my day.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you use this `AddFoodScreen` component? Is there any conditional rendering present there? For example `if (some_condition) { return <AddFoodScreen />; } else { return null; }`

Comment: its in my Stack Navigator and I navigate to this screen on pressing on a touchable component. The problem is not rendering the screen but filtering the data. Once I type in the TextInput to filder my data it renders the data in the flatlist and I get this memory leak error....

Comment: Well this memory leak could happen when you search for something and the re-rendering (this line: `setData(filteredData)`) of the component gets postponed, because of the debounce. Then the component gets unmounted and the postponed re-render executes, but it can't re-render the component since it was unmounted, which could potentially cause a memory leak.

Comment: Try removing the debounce and see if the warning will show up

Comment: yeah I removed it, my handleSearch looks like this now : 
`const handleSearch = (text) => {
    const formatQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    console.log(text);
    const filteredData = foodData.filter((filteredFood) => {
      if (filteredFood.title.toLowerCase().includes(formatQuery)) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        filteredFood.synonym &&
        filteredFood.synonym.toLowerCase().includes(formatQuery)
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    setQuery(formatQuery);
    setData(filteredData);
  };`

Comment: But I still get the error `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`